# Controlling unique access on Android 6+

Tags: android, uniqueidentifier

I currently develop an enterprise application on Android (that isn't on the Play Store) and we work on a licence based model.

So until now, we limit the number of installations of this app by the MAC address of the wifi adapter but this is no longer possible on android 5+ because a constant `02:00:00:00:00:00` is always returned.

Since the tablets we provide doesn't even have the Google services installed (so there's no Google account linked), what would be a nice new approach to limit the installations on this hardware from now on?

Comment: "we limit the number of installations of this app by the MAC address" -- how? Are you sending the MAC to your server as a device ID? If so, generate a local UUID and save it on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). Then, warn customers that if they uninstall/reinstall the app, or click Clear Data, or set up another user profile on a device, that they'll consume another license. Adjust your pricing to take this into account.

Comment: To flip it around, anything that involves trying to find some immutable device ID is doomed to failure, as Google is getting rid of those, for privacy reasons.